# Alerting based on DNS lookup

Tags: prometheus, prometheus-alertmanager, prometheus-blackbox-exporter

I currently have some alerting rules based on the "tcp_connect" and "http_2xx" probes that indicate a TCP and HTTP issues on a really high level, not yet to specific alerts.

Whenever a probe wasn't able to successfully speak to their target because of a issue with the DNS lookup, I either get an alert about the TCP connection from "tcp_connect" or one based on the HTTP status code (0) from "http_2xx", but neither of those two alerts are really correct.

I thought, maybe `probe_dns_lookup_time_seconds` is 0 whenever a DNS lookup failed, but this isn't the case, which is also logical when you think about it.

So I gave `probe_http_duration_seconds{phase="resolve"}` a try, which seems to be 0 when an issue with the DNS lookup occurred, but I'm not really convinced that this is the proper way of doing it.

I inspected the code responsible for the DNS lookup, and it seems that if there is either an error or it wasn't able to resolve the IP it returns a lookup time of "0.0".

https://github.com/prometheus/blackbox_exporter/blob/9935abb9a5ad75bf18e96a5b2b35b4e079948969/prober/utils.go#L94

I was hoping that I'd be able to get some reassurance that this is the proper way of doing this, or get some feedback to find a more fitting solution.

**Note**
I'm not talking about the DNS probe for DNS servers, or I might have a misunderstanding about what the DNS probe should be used for, obviously that's also a possibility!

Answer (score 0):

> I was hoping that I'd be able to get some reassurance that this is the proper way of doing this, or get some feedback to find a more fitting solution.

The metric you want is `probe_success`, as you don't really care what is causing your endpoint to be down as you're going to alert on it one way or the other. Figuring out the exact issue can be done after you've been paged, and avoids having to maintain many fragile cause-specific alerts.

> I'm not talking about the DNS probe for DNS servers, or I might have a misunderstanding about what the DNS probe should be used for, obviously that's also a possibility!

Your understanding is correct.

Comment: I do like the more specific alerts in my case, because if it's an issue with the DNS or even the reachability of the server itself the application is running on I want to alert someone different than lets say it's the application itself returning a 503.

I do think that cause-specific alerts can be too specific, but I also think that it's worth having cause-specific alerts to some extent so that the right people know about the problem as soon as possible instead of someone who has to inform them about it.